# Factory method and generics

Tags: c#, generics, factory-method

I have the following interface and implementation:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IList<T> GetAll();
}

internal class TrendDataRepository : IRepository<TrendData>
{
    public IList<TrendData> GetAll()
    {
        //.. returns some specific data via Entity framework
    }
}
```

I'm going to have multiple implementations that all return different data by Entity Framework. At some point I want to represent the user a list of classes that implement the IRepository interface. I do this with the following code. This works great for me.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAvailableRepositoryClasses()
    {
        var repositories = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                           where t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IRepository<>))
                           select t.Name;

        return repositories;
    }
```

However, I would also like to create a factory method that given a specific string will return a concrete Repository type and allow me to call the 'GetAll' method on it. In pseudo-code:

```
someObject = Factory.CreateInstance("TrendData");
someObject.GetAll();
```

(I know this won't work because I have to specify a concrete type in the factory method).

I desire this functionality because I want to give a user the ability to bind a report to a specific datasource. This way they can start a new report where the datasource of the report is bound to (for example) the TrendDataRepository.GetAll() method.

However, maybe because the end of the world is getting near ;-) or it's Friday afternoon and I just can't think clearly any more, I don't know how to realise this.

Some pointers would be really welcomed.

Comment: Have you looked at `Activator.CreateInstance()`?

Comment: Lee, that's what I'm doing with the reflection part. I just need it the other way around. Create a factory that given a specific string will instantiate the correct concrete type for me to use.

Comment: @Sardaukar - Yes, but you already load all the repository types and then select the names. Can't you just keep the types and just display the names? Then you can just use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the selected repository.

Comment: @Lee, that could work. Could you give me some demo code? I wasn't aware of the existence of Activator.CreateInstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest returning the collection of repository types instead of the names and just displaying the names in the UI:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAvailableRepositoryClasses()
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IRepository<>)));
}
```

Then when a user selects the source you can do:

```
object repository = Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType);
```

This method requires each repository to have a default constructor.

`Activator.CreateInstance` return an object, and you can't cast it to your `IRepository<T>` interface unless you know the generic type `T` you're expecting. The best solution is probably to create a non-generic `IRepository` interface which your repository classes also implement:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IList<object> GetAll();
}
```

Now you can cast your created repositories to `IRepository`:

```
IRepository repository = (IRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType);
```

you might to create a repository base class which implements both:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>, IRepository
{
    public abstract IList<T> GetAll();
    IList<object> IRepository.GetAll()
    {
        return this.GetAll().Cast<object>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. But with CreateInstance you get an Object as return value. Since it is an object, the consuming client will not now that there is a GetAll() method on it (defined in the interface).

Comment: @Sardaukar - Well you can't use generics unless you know the generic type you're expecting, which you won't if the user is selecting the data source. I've added an update using a non-generic interface.

Comment: You can cast it to an IRepository before you return it

Comment: @Lee, Thanks, I'll look into it. You have give me some good pointers.